# TextBox.Focus() only works if I have a MessageBox.Show() after it?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, focus

Ok so obviously there's more to it, but here's the basics.  This is seemingly such a simple thing but it's not working.

I have a Label.
I have a TextBox.

The ZIndex of the Label = "1"
The ZIndex of the TextBox = "0"

i.e. They are on top of one another and the TextBox is invisible.

When the user clicks on the LABEL (right now Via PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown but will be a command in ViewModel after this "works") the application should set focus to the TextBox.

Simple right?  Wrong...

If I have this code...it does NOT work.

```
    private void inVisTxtBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            inVisTxtBox.Focus();
//            TextBox_MouseDown(sender, e);
        }
```

If I have this code...it DOES work

```
 private void inVisTxtBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            inVisTxtBox.Focus();
//            TextBox_MouseDown(sender, e);
            MessageBox.Show("This is ridiculous");
        }
```

And finally the XAML:

```
 <Ctrls:AControl x:Class="<location of class>"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:CommandControls="clr-namespace:<location of custom controls>" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid Margin="0,15,15,15">
        <!--<Button Height="50" Click="Button_Click">FOC</Button>-->
        <TextBox x:Name="inVisTxtBox" Focusable="True" Grid.ZIndex="0" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
        <Label Grid.ZIndex="1" Margin="5" Content="243234234234234" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="inVisTxtBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
               x:Name="KeyPress_TextBox"/>
    </Grid>
</Ctrls:AControl>
```

**EDIT**

If I make the Label into a Templated Button with a label as it's template it works:

```
<Button x:Name="KeyPress_TextBox" Grid.ZIndex="1" Margin="5" Content="243234234234234" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Click="KeyPress_TextBox_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Why is that?

Must have something to do with the way the events route/bubble?

I have it working now by doing that...but I'm more curious what's happening.

Also...none of the following works either:

```
Keyboard.Focus(inVisTxtBox);
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(MainGrid,inVisTxtBox);
Keyboard.Focus(inVisTxtBox);
```

Comment: you mentioned that the TextBox is invisible? Why is that? and if it is actually invisible, whats the point of focusing it without actually making it visible?

Comment: it's not "invisible" per se.  It's behind the label.  The reason for this is I'm creating a "Key Press" control that will not have focus, but will display what the user types.   Example:  1.  User clicks on Label.  2.  TextBox gets focus.   3.  User begins typing.  4. Label is bound to TextBox Text property.  5.  Label is updated but user does not see blinking cursor, etc..

Comment: now I am confused. But if all you are trying to do is "Set the focus to the TextBox when the Label is clicked", then the code above should work, without the MessageBox. Are you sure you set the event on the right place? From the name of the event handler, it seems to be generated for the TextBox.

Comment: I 100% agree...the code should work.  Did you by chance try it?  It doesn't work.  The TextBox never gets focused.  The cursor is never blinking.  KeyBoard focus is never applied.  The event naming is just weird because I've been trying different things.  The event is wired up properly...I've put breakpoints to confirm.  This is really odd.  I'm sure it's something minor and stupid...but I'd like to know what's happening.  If I replace it with a BUTTON it does work  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and it works fine for me, even with previewmouseclick, something else seems to be the problem.

Likely throwing the message box up stops the focus from shifting to whatever it was going to shift to after the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event fires. Perhaps the UserControl itself is getting focus?

Comment: No dice...I've tried every mouse down event you can try and I've also tried every one with e.handled = true just for kicks.  If you've got your DEV environment opened for WPF, it's an easy one to try and replicate if you want to see if I'm nuts or not :).  Create a label, create a text box.  Pick a mousedown event for the label and say "TextBox".Focus()

Comment: @user1631520 I copied your code and it works fine for me, even with previewmouseclick, something else seems to be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying that KDiTraglia.  That's actually very helpful to know.  I just switched to MouseLeftButtonUP and it works now.  Something in my UserControl must be grabbing focus along the way.

Comment: @user1631520 Yeah, likely throwing the message box up stops the focus from shifting to whatever it was going to shift to after the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event fires.  Perhaps the UserControl itself is getting focus?

Comment: if you could post your last comment as the Answer I'll gladly mark it.

Comment: @user1631520 Did you figure out the issue?